# how to make link button on result(video_title) from sql db to show video_link?

Tags: php, html

https://www.webslesson.info/2016/05/how-to-search-multiple-words-at-a-time-in-mysql-php.html

on this site showing example of How to search multiple words at a time in Mysql ph
and i want to make an improve to this example. like after showing reuslt of (video_title) if i click on result(video_title) it shows www.whatever.com(video_link).

```
$condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);
                      $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_video WHERE " . $condition;
                      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql_query);
                      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                      {
                           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                           {
                                echo '<tr><td>'.$row["video_title"].'</td></tr>';
                           }
                      }
                      else
                      {
                           echo '<label>Data not Found</label>';
                      }
                 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your column name is `video_link`
So you should modify the echo line with

```
 echo '<tr><td><a href="' . $row["video_link"] . '">' . $row["video_title"] . '</a></td></tr>';
```

With your optional text :

```
if( !empty($row) ){
    echo '<tr><td><a href="' . $row["video_link"] . '">' . $row["video_title"] . $row["video_optionnal_text"] . '</a></td></tr>';
} else {
    echo '<tr><td><a href="' . $row["video_link"] . '">' . $row["video_title"] . '</a></td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: what if i want to show texts instead of link is code still the same?

Comment: The code actually show the title of your video ^^ If you want to put any other text, just change the text between <a> and </a>

Comment: i mean if in the video_link instead of url if there is text which part of code should i change?

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: like on my db video_link has www.google.com but what i wanna show is text if i change www.google.com to 'this video is really good!' so when i click on the result(video_title) to show this video is really good!

Comment: You should create a new column (optionnal) like... `video_optional_text`. Then you just have to check. If there is some text, you display it, else, you show the title. Probably something like that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189430/discussion-between-kwanhee-hwang-and-eiji).